# arcgis graph vs .net graph

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, graph

I am trying to show some elevation/cross section data in a graph. I am trying to do this in arcgis graphs. But because of my previous graph work was in .net, I found arcobjects.net API for graphing is not so much coder friendly. So, now I want to go back in .net graphs. But before that I want to be confirm that, I am not doing any kind of mistakes. So I goggled for advantage and disadvantage of arcgis graphs from coder perspective. But I couldn't find that much information there. So I want some help from experts.

**EDIT :**
Based on selecting water-body from the map, I am showing a graph. This graph shows elevation value of that water-body's elevation. If user selects another water-body, then another series will be added. I am showing this graph from my add-in. It's not necessary to show it within ArcGIS Desktop's graphing framework. But if I can show it from ArcGIS Desktop's graphing framework, it will be great.

For graphing, which one would be good .net graphs or arcgis graphs?

Comment: More details are needed before this can be answered. What are you doing with the graphs? Where are you displaying it? Do you need the graphs to fit into ArcGIS Desktop's graphing framework? Or are you just displaying it within your application/addin/extension?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: I have edited my question according to your comment. Can you please have a look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in saying that ArcGIS Desktop's Garphing framework is not very developer friendly. If you want to access it, and create graphs, you need to use the [IDataGraphT](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000034p000000) interface. There are many samples and snippets linked on the documentation page.

I personally hate the graphs in ArcGIS Desktop. They are ugly, and you don't really have much customizability, either via code, or via the UI.
That is why, if you just need to show a graph to the user, I would suggest that you use whichever library you know, and have developing experience with. You will have more control over it, and you will get a good looking graph quickly.

And looking at your requirements, I'm not even sure it will be possible to do (in a straightforward way) what you want with ArcGIS Desktop's Graph.

Comment: I did my work with arcgis graphs, but it looks like whenever I need customization, it will be painful for me. And actually I wanted to give some customization control on user's hand also(if possible). And it looks like its not possible using ArcGIS graphs

Comment: The thing with ArcGIS Graphs is that they require an ITable. In a case like yours, you need to create a Temporary/In memory table, and then apply the data on top of that.  And that might not be the easiest or elegant option.

Comment: Actually I have feature class table with elevation data. So I just need to pass a query.

Comment: You can use `ISeriesProperties.WhereClause` to apply your query.

Comment: Yes. I did that. As I told you, I already did my work with arcgis graphs. But I wanted to know which one would be good for future. That is why I asked the question. :)